# Is there any way to have a LaTeX compiler on a Mac without root access?

Tags: installing, mac

Long story short, I have limited install rights on my Mac. I believe the only limitation is that I can only write files inside my user directory. I also have limited read rights to files outside my user directory. So, is there a way to install LaTeX on a Mac without root access? I do know about online alternatives such as ShareLaTeX, but my internet coverage is spotty on occasion and I compile frequently to see what the final result is since I'm not very good at using LaTeX.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

according to [this](http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php?ti) tutorial it should be possible, you just need to manually install files in your home directory:

### intalling TeXLive without root access

Since installing MacTeX without root access requires some non trivial cutomizations, I sugget you to install TeXLive instead, with this easy method (I'll add a tutorial for MacTex when I have more time):

1) Download the TeXLive [install script](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz)
2) extract the tar archive with your preferred software
3) run the install script with `./install-tl`
4) you'll be prompted with this screen

```
======================> TeX Live installation procedure <=====================

=======> Note: Letters/digits in <angle brackets> indicate menu items <=======
=======>       for commands or configurable options                   <=======

 Detected platform: <your platform>

 <B> platforms: 1 out of 18

 <S> installation scheme (scheme-full)
     84 collections out of 85, disk space required: 3739 MB

 Customizing installation scheme:
   <C> standard collections
   <L> language collections

 <D> directories:
   TEXDIR (the main TeX directory):
     !! default location: /usr/local/texlive/2012
     !! is not writable, please select a different one!
   TEXMFLOCAL (directory for site-wide local files):
     /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
   TEXMFSYSVAR (directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var
   TEXMFSYSCONFIG (directory for local config):
     /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-config
   TEXMFVAR (personal directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     ~/.texlive2012/texmf-var
   TEXMFCONFIG (personal directory for local config):
     ~/.texlive2012/texmf-config
   TEXMFHOME (directory for user-specific files):
     ~/texmf

 <O> options:
   [ ] use letter size instead of A4 by default
   [X] allow execution of restricted list of programs via \write18
   [X] create all format files
   [X] install macro/font doc tree
   [X] install macro/font source tree

 <V> set up for portable installation

Actions:
 <I> start installation to hard disk
 <H> help
 <Q> quit
```

the most interesting part is `<D>`, you need to move all the directories starting with `/usr` in a convenient place in your home folder. To do this, just type `d` and press enter, you'll be prompted with this second screen:

```
===============================================================================
Directories setup:

!! The default location as given below is forbidden or
!! can't be written to.
!! Either change the destination directory using <1> or create it
!! outside this script.
 <1> TEXDIR:       /usr/local/texlive/2012
     support tree: /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf

 <2> TEXMFLOCAL:     /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
 <3> TEXMFSYSVAR:    /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var
 <4> TEXMFSYSCONFIG: /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-config

 <5> TEXMFVAR:       ~/.texlive2012/texmf-var
 <6> TEXMFCONFIG:    ~/.texlive2012/texmf-config
 <7> TEXMFHOME:      ~/texmf

 Note: ~ will expand to $HOME (or to %USERPROFILE% on Windows)

Actions:
 <R> return to main menu
 <Q> quit
```

just type `1` and enter the directory where you want to install texlive, e.g. `<your home>/Library/texlive/2012`. After you change the first directory, all the other will be moved accordingly. After setting the directories return to the main installation screen `R` and the start the installation with `I`. Done.

Comment: It is worthwhile to make this standalone irrespective of the mac-wiki link with some explanation to make it newbie friendly.

Comment: Could you clarify? I'm not quite sure what the wiki page's instructions are. It seems to be just stating that it is possible to install in the user directory. I don't believe it actually says how.

Comment: sorry, I thought the wiki instructions were straightforward, I'll update my answer with more details asap.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply, but this works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: another possibility: `TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/you/want/texlive ./install-tl`. Note that the default `scheme-full` leads to a 5.7 gig download! the `small` scheme sits at a more reasonable 180 mb